# Of a list of properties, check which property an object has? Object can only have one of the properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

An object can have either property a, b, c, or d.

What’s the best way find out which one it has?

```
var input = {
    name: 'Bob',
    a: 1
}
```

Expected output:

```
a
```

I was previously using:

```
_.keys(_.pick(input, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))[0]
```

But was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Comment: `if ("a" in input)` comes to mind ?

Comment: Or if you want to return the properties, `Object.keys`

Comment: You can use `_.intersection()` to get the intersection of the list of keys and the list of keys that may only appear once. If the intersection contains just one key, then that's the answer; if more than one then the object is breaking the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is better but a smidgeon more expressive perhaps:

```
    var result = _.find('abcd', function(key){
        return _.has(input,key);
    })
```

Comment: Or `some()` instead of `find()` - if you want a boolean result, instead of the found string.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Not sure if it is "better" but it will get you out of having to use another library plus should be a little lighter.

```js
var input = {
    a: 1
}

function whichProperty(obj) {
    var possibilities = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    return possibilities.filter(function (a) {
        return obj[a];
    })[0];
}

document.write(whichProperty(input));
```